# Is it really necessary to ground the metal can on crystal oscillators?

Tags: pcb-design, noise, oscillator, grounding, crystal

I am modifying a KOSS portable dvd player into a portable raspberry pi computer and have noticed that they grounded the can of the crystal that feeds their microcontroller. I am curious if there is an electrical benefit to this? Maybe this bodge was purely for mechanical adhesion?

I have designed quite a few embedded systems which have crystal oscillators in noisy applications but have never (to my knowledge) experienced an issue with an un-grounded crystal can. This is the first I am seeing this.

I'm just genuinely curious as to why this was done.

Side note: I love finding bodges in the real-world (0ohm shunt to fix the floating ground in the copper pour on the upper left of the crystal).

[image]

Comment: Is that an actual production device?

Comment: haha yea this was a portable DVD player purchased off the shelf from best buy over ten years ago!

Comment: Maybe an EMI reduction 'field enhancement'.

Comment: Agree,  Typically this type of mod late in the development stage is an EMC mod, esp since it's the can on the xtal.